# Inversion in Wh-questions

Tags: questions, subject-verb-inversion

What is difference between:

- Why I am studying?
- Why am I studying?

Comment: I may be wrong here, but I think *"Why I am studying"* might be "valid" in Indian English. Or maybe it's just a common "error" among Indians who aren't meaningfully "native speaker" Anglophones in the first place. We'd need some genuine IE speakers to pronounce on that one.

Comment: 'Why I am studying' is not a question, and requires no question mark. It is perhaps the title of an essay which explains why the author is studying.  'Why am I studying', on the other hand, is a valid question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one is not really a well-formed question in English. Placing the verb right after the interrogative word is the usual way to create an interrogative sentence. Thus: "Why *am* I studying?", "Where *is* the station?", "How *does* this device work?", "Who *can* lift the stone?"

The other word order would make sense in a clause, but not as a stand-alone sentence. Thus: "I wonder why I am studying," or "She asked me why I am studying." Notice that these sentences are not questions, but statements.